# How to user User dictionary to indication hyphenation

Tags: adobe-indesign, hyphenation

I’m trying to build a custom hyphenation dictionary, and with the ressources I found, it doesn’t seams to work.

Right now, I have a User dictionary, containing one word with a required hyphenation. It doesn’t work .

My user dictionary
[image: My user dictionary]
And my document with the dictionary
[image: And my document with the dictionary]

Comment: Have you made sure that the paragraph style for the text is set to Canadian French?

Comment: Yup. In the end, it worked following this guide: https://creativepro.com/tip-week-controlling-hyphenation/ !

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose **user dictionary** from the **hyphenation menu**. Now „HUNSPELL“ is selected. Also the language in the paragraph style or text itself has to be french canadian.

Comment: Hi Jenny, thanks for the answer. I tried selecting User Dictionary Only, but now the word just didn’t hyphen at all. According to Adobe, the User dictionary are indeed added to the selected dictionary (Hunspell in this case).